# Python - Tkinter event_generate not detected by bind

Tags: python, events, tkinter, frame

I have two classes (one called 'Point' one called 'PointConector'), both of which inherits 'Frame' (Im not sure If I need to but was seeing if it helped)

When I move the Point (mouse Enter/Leave) and drag the point around, I want to fire off an event for 'PointConnector' (which is a line thats joins the twp points)  to pick up the event and redraw the line with the new position of the point.

If I use the event_generate from the canvas object and bind also from the canvas object then the event is picked up, but the object that is passed is the canvas object, not the Point object.

If I fire the event_generate from the Point object (which is inherited from Frame) then the event is ignored

I need the bind event to have the Widget field set to the 'Point' that generated the event. ie I need to have a handle to the point that fired the event. So the Field 'Widget' in the event should be the Point object that is being handled, not the canvas.

```py
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas,Frame

class pointConnector(Frame):
    point1 = None
    point2 = None
    connector = None

    def __init__(self,canvas, point1,point2):
        super(pointConnector,self).__init__(canvas)

        self.point1 = point1
        self.point2 = point2
        self.canvas = canvas
        p1 = self.canvas.translatePoint((self.point1.x,self.point1.y))
        p2 = self.canvas.translatePoint((self.point2.x,self.point2.y))

        self.connector = canvas.create_line(p1[0], p1[1], p2[0], p2[1],fill='red',state="hidden", width =2)

        self.canvas.bind("<<foo>>",self.dummy)

    def dummy(self,event):
        print("Virtual Event Data: {}".format(event))

    def show(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.connector,state="normal")

class screen(Canvas):
    width =0
    height=0
    cY = 0
    cX = 0

    items =[]
    dragItem = None
    mouseOverItem = None

    def setScreenSize(self,width,height):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.cX = int(width/2)
        self.cY = int(height/2)

    def __init__(self,root, unit,width,height):
        super(screen,self).__init__(root,width=width,height=height)
        self.root = root
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setScreenSize(width,height)

        self.tag_bind('DRAG_OBJECT','<ButtonPress-1>',self.onStartDrag)
        self.tag_bind('DRAG_OBJECT','<ButtonRelease-1>',self.onEndDrag)
        self.tag_bind('DRAG_OBJECT','<B1-Motion>',self.onDrag)


        self.bind("<Configure>", self.configure)



    def addObject(self,object):
        self.items.append(object)


    def findObject(self,tags):
        for item in self.items:
            if str(item.id) in tags:
                return item
        return None


    def onStartDrag(self,event):
        self.dragItem= self.find_closest(event.x,event.y)
        wt = self.gettags(self.dragItem)
        self.dragItem = self.findObject(wt)

    def onEndDrag(self,event):
        self.dragItem = None

    def onDrag(self,event):
            self.dragItem.move(event.x,event.y)

    def draw(self):
        # Draw array of items
        for o in self.items:
            o.show()

    def translateX(self,x):
        return (x + self.cX)  

    def translateY(self,y):
        return (y + self.cY)  

    def translatePoint(self,pointxy):
        return (self.translateX(pointxy[0]),self.translateY(pointxy[1]))

class point(Frame):

    state = "normal"
    x : int
    y : int
    def setPoint(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __init__(self,canvas,x,y,radius,ObjectName):
        super(point,self).__init__(canvas)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.radius = radius
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.ObjectName= ObjectName
        self.id = None
        self.create_point()

    def create_point(self):
        x = self.canvas.translateX(self.x)
        y = self.canvas.translateY(self.y)
        self.circle = self.canvas.create_oval(x-self.radius,y-self.radius,x+self.radius,y+self.radius,state=self.state,fill='yellow')
        self.text = self.canvas.create_text(x,y,text=self.ObjectName,state=self.state )
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.circle, tags=({"type":"POINT", "name":self.ObjectName},"DRAG_OBJECT"))
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text, tags=({"type":"POINT", "name":self.ObjectName},"DRAG_OBJECT"))

        self.id = {"type":"POINT", "name":self.ObjectName}

    def show(self):
        newX = self.canvas.translateX(self.x)
        newY = self.canvas.translateY(self.y)

        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.circle,state='normal')
        self.canvas.coords(self.circle,(newX-self.radius,newY-self.radius,newX + self.radius, newY + self.radius))
        self.canvas.coords(self.text,(newX,newY))

        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text,state='normal')
        self.canvas.tag_raise(self.circle)
        self.canvas.tag_raise(self.text)

    def hide(self):
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.circle,state='hidden')
        self.canvas.itemconfig(self.text,state='hidden')

    def move (self,x,y):
        delta_x = x- (self.x + self.canvas.cX)  
        delta_y = y- (self.y + self.canvas.cY) 
        self.canvas.move(self.circle,delta_x,delta_y)
        self.canvas.move(self.text,delta_x,delta_y)
        self.x = x - self.canvas.cX
        self.y = y - self.canvas.cY 

        ## If I use the canvas object (that is passed in) then the Point object picks up the event, but then I cant tell which 'Point' is begin dragged
        #self.canvas.event_generate("<<foo>>",x=self.x,y=self.y,when='now')

        ## If I generate the event from the Point Object then the Event is lost
        self.event_generate("<<foo>>",x=self.x,y=self.y,when='tail')


        self.update()    
# Start of program
print("Start --->")
tk = Tk()
mainScreen = screen(tk,20,700,700)
mainScreen.pack(fill="both",expand=1)

# Add Point A
pointA = point(mainScreen,0,0,10,"A",)
mainScreen.addObject(pointA)

# Add Point B
pointB = point(mainScreen,20,20,10,"B")
mainScreen.addObject(pointB)

LineA = pointConnector(mainScreen,pointA,pointB)
mainScreen.addObject(LineA)

mainScreen.draw()
tk.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code won't run as posted. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: It is hard to tell why your class `Point` inherit from `Frame`; as far as I can tell, it should probably be a canvas item, which in a bare `tk.Canvas` is a unique integer id.

Comment: A [mcve] should be included directly in the question. Links to code on other sites is discouraged here.

Comment: Inheriting from Frame was an attempt to get the events working. I assumed there might be base class functionality needed. I was not sure what, if anything, I needed to inherit from. I can try have both classes inherit from canvas.

Comment: @BryanOakley  -  Ill try get a working example in one code block and update the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley - code example updated :-)